# How to increase the maximum number of open files on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, ulimit, open-files

I want to increase the maximum number of open files in Fedora 27,
since the default settings are too low:

```
$ ulimit -Sn
1024
$ ulimit -Hn
4096
```

First, I ensure that the system-wide setting is high enough, by adding
the following line to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
fs.file-max=100000
```

Then, I set the user-specific settings by adding the following lines to
`/etc/security/limits.conf` (`root` must be added separately since the
Wildcard matches all users *except* root):

```
*     soft  nofile 100000
*     hard  nofile 100000
root  soft  nofile 100000
root  hard  nofile 100000
```

To ensure that the above settings are actually loaded, I have added
the following line to `/etc/pam.d/login`:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

After rebooting my computer and logging in, I still get the same
results for `ulimit -Sn` and `ulimit -Hn`.  Only the system-wide
setting have been set:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
100000
```

I'm a bit at a loss as to what to do...  Anybody have any ideas how I might diagnose/solve this?

Comment: You could add `debug` to the line in `/etc/pam.d/login`. I just double checked on a FC27 and the `pam_limits.so` is also in the pam modules `system-auth`, `sudo`, `runuser`, `password-auth`... also check with `journalctl -f` which pam module is triggered on login.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that the GUI (and gnome-terminal) are started by `systemd --user`, which does not read from `/etc/security/limits.conf`. Instead, you should edit `/etc/systemd/user.conf` and `/etc/systemd/system.conf` for the soft and hard limits, respectively, by appending e.g.

```
DefaultLimitNOFILE=100000
```

This same question has come up a few times on the StackExchange network; see e.g. [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1200539/cannot-increase-open-file-limit-past-4096-ubuntu) for further discussion.

There are also bug reports for the issue, both for [Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1627769) and [Fedora](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1364332).

Answer (score 0):

Also, check your `~/.bashrc` file for `ulimit` usage.

In my Fedora 38 I found that in my ~/.bashrc there where line

```
limit -n 4096
```

so updating it resolved the issue.